# link is not coming on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

This is my simple code in html..

```
<p class="backto">
    <a href="http://saisukamal.com">
   <img src=<?php echo base_url()."images/img_top1.gif";?>><br/>
   <span style="margin-right: -5px;">Home</span></a>
 </p>
  <p class="backto1">
   <a href="http://saisukamal.com/contactus.html">
    <img src=<?php echo base_url()."images/img_top3.gif";?>><br/>
    <span style="margin-right: -5px;">Contact</span></a>
  </p>
```

First link is working but second is not. When I remove p class, then it works. It may be overriding. So what will be the solution for that??

Comment: It's not going to that page and pointer is not coming for hover.

Comment: `cursor:pointer;` will bring back the pointer. your `<a>` tag is looking fine. It should work.

Comment: any css associated with it?

Comment: put css on your issue and the best way is to create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's the way you've built your image tags. The quotes are not created properly because the existing quotes are for the string in your echo which could throw off your HTML.

```
<p class="backto">
    <a href="http://saisukamal.com">
   <img src="<?php echo base_url()."images/img_top1.gif";?>"><br/>
   <span style="margin-right: -5px;">Home</span></a>
 </p>
  <p class="backto1">
   <a href="http://saisukamal.com/contactus.html">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url()."images/img_top3.gif";?>"><br/>
    <span style="margin-right: -5px;">Contact</span></a>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hover demo</title>
  <script>

  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
a{
    cursor: pointer;
}
  </style>

</head>
<body>
<p class="backto">
    <a href="http://saisukamal.com">
   <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/img_top1.gif"><br/>
   <span style="margin-right: -5px;">Home</span></a>
 </p>
  <p class="backto1">
   <a href="http://saisukamal.com/contactus.html">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>images/img_top1.gif"><br/>
    <span style="margin-right: -5px;">Contact</span></a>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't a valid answer. They're not getting a pointer because the browser doesn't recognize the `href` as a hyperlink. Forcing a pointer is not going to change that.